# Phantom Cassandra driver dependency error

Tags: scala, sbt, phantom-dsl

I would like to use the phantom cassandra wrapper in my scala project, but when I try to update my sbt build I get a dependency error.

---

My build.sbt:

```
version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

seq(lsSettings :_*)

libraryDependencies ++=  Seq(
  "org.clapper" %% "grizzled-scala" % "1.2",
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
  "org.rauschig" % "jarchivelib" % "0.6.0",
  "com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "3.0.0",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.0" % "test",
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.2.0",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.10",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.2",
  "com.websudos"  % "phantom-dsl_2.10" % "1.2.0"
  )


resolvers += "grizzled-scala-resolver-0" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

---

I get the following error:

---

```
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-pgp:0.8.1 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
```

---

Don't know what I have to do...

edit:

Answer from https://github.com/websudosuk/phantom/issues/119

error is on the pom side, new version 1.2.1 coming soon...

Comment: Looks like a mismatch on scala version - you are specifying 2.10 for phantom whereas the rest of your project is using 2.11. Try "com.websudos"  %% "phantom-dsl" % "1.2.0"

Comment: I tried it and it still gives me the same error. Using scala 2.10 produces the same error as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from https://github.com/websudosuk/phantom/issues/119

error is on the pom side, new version 1.2.1 coming soon...